# Parsing different types of formats with regular expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I need to parse (split) some sentences in my DB with some specific requirement.
These sentences can have different type of formats, 80% of my sentences have one of the following formats:

1. COMPANY_NAME, CITY_NAME_1 (STREET_ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE CITY_NAME_2). ANY_STRING
2. COMPANY_NAME, CITY_NAME_1, STREET_ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE CITY_NAME_2. ANY_STRING
3. COMPANY_NAME, CITY_NAME_1, STREET_ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE CITY_NAME_2, (ANY_STRING: ANY_STRING.). ANY_STRING
4. COMPANY_NAME (ANY_STRING), CITY_NAME_1, STREET_ADDRESS, ZIP_CODE CITY_NAME_2. ANY_STRING

Here, I have specified the rules:

- COMPANY_NAME can have spaces, hyphons (-), dots.
- COMPANY_NAME can not have comma, breakets
- CITY_NAME_1 and CITY_NAME_2 can have space, slashes, breakets
- CITY_NAME_1 and CITY_NAME_2 can not have comma
- CITY_NAME_1 and CITY_NAME_2 are same in 95% of cases but they are
  different in 5% of cases
- STREET_ADDRESS can have anything (comma, breaket, any special
  charcter etc.)
- ZIP_CODE is already known to me (A 4 or 5 or 6 digit numeric string).

I have already zip code of each sentence is with me. And I want to create regular expressions or function which will take sentence and zip code as input and return street name as output.

Of cource I can create the functions for each of the above method differently. But, how can I know that given sentence fits to which format? Is it possible to know this with regular expression?

Comment: Try to parse it as [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: Have you tried anything? How about using `explode(', ', $sentence);`?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried with explode and etc. PHP functions, but I wanto to go with regular expressions also. The reason I want to go with regex is these formats can be added more in future. So at that time I should only write one regex for new format added. I should not change the whole script. So please suggest me some regex expressions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but that's one of the worst ideas to store data in a database. If you want to go crazy with your database AT LEAST let the strings be serialized objects.

Comment: @Ravi, are all these (`delimiter`) symbols are escaped in the data parts ? If it is so, it is still possible to find a solution. If they are not escaped, possibly `regexp` will filter smth., but again head aching task.

Comment: If possible you should seriously consider changing the design of your database. If you can't, then I feel sorry for you :(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what type of string it is (how it is delimited).
Through `preg_match()`. The `regexp` seems to be kinda complicated for this situation first of all bec. we don't have data.

http://myregexp.com/ - will help you to compose `regexp`s.